# Module Not Found Error In importing ConvNet

Tags: python-3.x

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
```

> File "C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/CNN model training.py", line 8, in
>   
>       from model.cnn import ConvNet
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Comment: Apparently i have a problem in import ConvNet and i tried to install model.cnn in anaconda prompt, it shows me package not found error. The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: Did you add `__init__.py` in the model directory ?